# Why TextBox validation doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I wish to validate this `TextBox` against negative values and characters (must be integer without decimal)
It works well for `.` but I am not able to understand why it accepts negative value and characters?

My code is :

```
private void txtLifeMonths_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar == '.') && (e.KeyChar >= 0) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the first `&&` operator with `||` and also move it to the end of your `if` statement then it should works as you want. Like this:

```
private void txtLifeMonths_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar >= 0) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back) || (e.KeyChar == '.'))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Yaah thanks it worked, But why i needed to replace && with or ?

Comment: @testtest ... Because you don't want to evaluate the second operand which validates for `.` with the first operand. If the second operand evaluates to true `e.Handled` should be `true`